# Timed out waiting for a YugaByte DB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

```
ubuntu@vps-9b30a7d3:~/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1$ ./bin/yb-ctl create
Creating cluster.
Waiting for cluster to be ready.
Viewing file /home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.err:
sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1/bin/yb-tserver: not found
Viewing file /home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/master.err:
sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1/bin/yb-master: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 2021, in <module>
    control.run()
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 1998, in run
    self.args.func()
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 1755, in create_cmd_impl
    self.wait_for_cluster_or_raise()
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 1598, in wait_for_cluster_or_raise
    raise RuntimeError("Timed out waiting for a YugaByte DB cluster!")
RuntimeError: Timed out waiting for a YugaByte DB cluster!
Viewing file /tmp/tmpfY6csf:
2020-08-02 10:15:38,864 INFO: Starting master-1 with:
/home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1/bin/yb-master --fs_data_dirs "/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1" --webserver_interface 127.0.0.1 --rpc_bind_addresses 127.0.0.1 --v 0 --version_file_json_path=/home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1 --webserver_doc_root "/home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1/www" --replication_factor=1 --yb_num_shards_per_tserver 2 --ysql_num_shards_per_tserver=2 --default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.35 --master_addresses 127.0.0.1:7100 --enable_ysql=true >"/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/master.out" 2>"/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/master.err" &
2020-08-02 10:15:38,871 INFO: Starting tserver-1 with:
/home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1/bin/yb-tserver --fs_data_dirs "/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1" --webserver_interface 127.0.0.1 --rpc_bind_addresses 127.0.0.1 --v 0 --version_file_json_path=/home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1 --webserver_doc_root "/home/ubuntu/Database/yugabyte-2.1.8.1/www" --tserver_master_addrs=127.0.0.1:7100 --yb_num_shards_per_tserver=2 --redis_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:6379 --cql_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:9042 --local_ip_for_outbound_sockets=127.0.0.1 --use_cassandra_authentication=false --ysql_num_shards_per_tserver=2 --default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.65 --enable_ysql=true --pgsql_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:5433 >"/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.out" 2>"/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.err" &
2020-08-02 10:15:38,873 INFO: Waiting for master and tserver processes to come up.
2020-08-02 10:15:49,111 INFO: PIDs found: {'tserver': [None], 'master': [None]}
2020-08-02 10:15:49,113 ERROR: Failed waiting for master and tserver processes to come up.
^^^ Encountered errors ^^^
```

I have a test server setup in which i am trying to install yugabyte. Everytime i try to create a cluster it throws an error.On my local server i encountered the same error but when i checked cluster status It shows cluster is created.But on test server when i am checking status it shows no node created.Although yugabyte-data folder is getting created .

Comment: Can you check the contents of:

/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.err

and


/home/ubuntu/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/master.err

Perhaps there's a port conflict preventing one of the processes from coming up.

Comment: You can also check if either the yb-master/yb-tserver process hit a FATAL. The files can be located thus:

cd ~/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/

then

find . -name yb-tserver.FATAL -print

and also look for

find . -name yb-master.FATAL -print